# Reading JSON "not an object"

Tags: json, swift, geocoding

I am using this [JSON library](https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json) to get a location from Google Geocoding the following way:

```
let json = JSON(url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=94127&key=MY_API_KEY")
print(json)
```

It prints this:

> {"results":[{"geometry":{"viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":37.7513029,"lng":-122.442329},"southwest":{"lat":37.721569,"lng":-122.472671}},"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":37.7513029,"lng":-122.442329},"southwest":{"lat":37.721569,"lng":-122.472671}},"location":{"lat":37.734646,"lng":-122.463708},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE"},"formatted_address":"San Francisco, CA 94127, USA","types":["postal_code"],"address_components":[{"types":["postal_code"],"short_name":"94127","long_name":"94127"},{"types":["locality","political"],"short_name":"SF","long_name":"San Francisco"},{"types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"],"short_name":"San Francisco County","long_name":"San Francisco County"},{"types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"],"short_name":"CA","long_name":"California"},{"types":["country","political"],"short_name":"US","long_name":"United States"}],"place_id":"ChIJK9xbjZR9j4ARBsVPOdGWHs8"}],"status":"OK"}

Once formatted, to get the location, I need to dig down to `"results" -> "geometry" –> "location" –>"lat"/"lng"`.
When trying to print this:

```
print(json["results"]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"])
```

...I am getting the following error:

> Error Domain=JSONErrorDomain Code=500 "not an object" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=not an object}

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: `results` is an array, so there should be some indexing before `geometry`.

Comment: Like how? `print(json["results"][0]["geometry"]…`?

Comment: I don't know that library but something like that.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion and @JianpingLiu's answer fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Sulthan mentioned, `"results"` is an array of which I need to pick an index.

```
print(json["results"][0]["geometry"]...
```

@JianpingLiu hinted me to the right direction. To access the data, I need to append `.data`.

The final solution therefor is:

```
print(json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"].data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is lat/lng is not Json object, they are Json data.

Try

```
print(json["results"]["geometry"]["location"].lat)
```

Updated:

@Sulthan, Thanks for the comment about the index thing.

```
  print(json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"].lat)
```

Comment: But Xcode doesn't know there is a `.lat`. I changed it (as suggested by Xcode) to `.data` but that gives me `nil`

Comment: Thank you too! You directed me to the solution. See my answer.